# How can I connect an android device emulator to the host pc?

Tags: android, usb, extract, emulation

I'm trying to extract data from an android device using LiME or AMExtractor, but I need an rooted phone and I can't do this with my personal device. So, I've trying to connect android emulators (bluestacks, nox app player, android studio virtual device, etc) to my host pc, like an USB connection or something.
So far, I couldn't do it, and I'm stucked at this for a few days now. Is it possible? If not, what could I do instead?
Sorry for any bad english.

Tried finding an option to connect the virtual device to host pc, but couldn't find it. Also tried an connection via IP, which also not worked. I'm really expecting that some emulator have this function.